# Kubernetes: How to check the autoscaling policy of my deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

#### Step1: I have created a deployment in the Kubernetes, here is my configuration.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: autoscaling-nginx
  name: autoscaling-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: autoscaling-nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: autoscaling-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

#### step2: then, I set an autoscaling policy for this deployment.

```
kubectl autoscale deployment autoscaling-nginx --min=5 --max=10 --cpu-percent=80
```

#### step3: `kubectl describe deployment`

I want to check the autoscaling policy for this deployment, but the output of `kubectl describe deployment autoscaling-nginx` doesn't contain the specified autoscaling policy.

```
Name:                   autoscaling-nginx
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 15 Aug 2023 03:30:32 +0000
Labels:                 app=autoscaling-nginx
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=autoscaling-nginx
Replicas:               5 desired | 5 updated | 5 total | 5 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=autoscaling-nginx
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   autoscaling-nginx-5b89cf756 (5/5 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  104s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set autoscaling-nginx-5b89cf756 to 2
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  24s   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set autoscaling-nginx-5b89cf756 to 5 from 2
```

### Question: How can I check the autoscaling policy for a deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Here are commands to check the autoscaling setting for a deployment

```
## List all autoscaling setting

kubectl get HorizontalPodAutoscaler


## Check a specific autoscaling setting
kubectl describe hpa  xxxxx
```

### Example

```
kubectl describe HorizontalPodAutoscaler nginx


Name:                                                  nginx
Namespace:                                             default
Labels:                                                <none>
Annotations:                                           <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                     Tue, 15 Aug 2023 03:46:45 +0000
Reference:                                             Deployment/nginx
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  <unknown> / 80%
Min replicas:                                          3
Max replicas:                                          6
Deployment pods:                                       3 current / 3 desired
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu in container nginx of Pod nginx-77b4fdf86c-vrckz
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age               From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----              ----                       -------
  Normal   SuccessfulRescale             38s               horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 3; reason: Current number of replicas below Spec.MinReplicas
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       8s (x2 over 23s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu in container nginx of Pod nginx-77b4fdf86c-vrckz
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  8s (x2 over 23s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), first error is: failed to get cpu resource metric value: failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu in container nginx of Pod nginx-77b4fdf86c-vrckz
```

### Reference

[Kubernetes: Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)